# How to find the total number of a certain element in an array(C)

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to create a complete C program to read ten alphabets and display them on the screen. I shall also have to find the number of a certain element and print it on the screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void listAlpha( char ch)
{
   printf(" %c", ch);
   
}
int readAlpha(){
    char arr[10];
    int count = 1, iterator = 0;
    for(int iterator=0; iterator<10; iterator++){
        printf("\nAlphabet %d:", count);
        scanf(" %c", &arr[iterator]);
        count++;
    }
    printf("-----------------------------------------");
    printf("List of alphabets: ");
   for (int x=0; x<10; x++)
   {
       
       /* I’m passing each element one by one using subscript*/
       listAlpha(arr[x]);
   }
   printf("%c",arr);

   return 0;
}

int findTotal(){
    
}
int main(){
    readAlpha();
}
```

The code should be added in the findTotal() element. The output is expected as below.

```
Output:
List of alphabets : C C C A B C B A C C //I've worked out this part.
Total alphabet A: 2
Total alphabet B: 2
Total alphabet C: 6

Alphabet with highest hit is C
```

Comment: The way you are reading `scanf(" %c", &arr[iterator]);` you are not storing the `\0` at the end

Comment: Do explain to me what this means. Like what is the use of adding \0 at the back of the array code.

Comment: if you add `\0` at the end of set of character stream then its called a string, it is then used properly for all string operations

Comment: @IrAM: `arr` can be used here as a plain array, so it can be one of the rare exception to the rule that a char array should be null terminated. But IMHO, that single fact should require a comment in bold or red flashing font ...

Comment: Asking  to fill in a function, such as `int findTotal(){
    
}` is really just asking for someone to code your program on a smaller scale.  Which really means that you have not yet done enough research .  The following method to do what you ask is [here](https://codeforwin.org/2015/07/c-program-to-find-frequency-of-each-element-in-array.html). (and many other places.) But certainly you should review the answers offered below for additional advice.

Comment: A character array: `char arr[] = {'a','b','c','d'};`  A C string: `char arr[] = {"abcd"};` (which is equivalent to: `char arr[] = {'a','b','c','d','\0'};`).  A C string is just a null terminated char array.  You do not need one here, but should make a clear note of that in your post so other swill know that explicitly.  (as already mentioned in comments, but not yet edited into your post.)

Answer (score 1):

The only run-time problem I see in your code is this statement:

```
printf("%c",arr);
```

Is wrong.  At this point in your program, `arr` is an array of `char`, not a single `char` as expected by the format specifier `%c`. For this to work, the `printf()` needs to be expanded to:

```
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",
         arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],arr[3],arr[4],
         arr[5],arr[6],arr[7],arr[8],arr[9]);
```

Or:  treat `arr` as a [string](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=C+string) rather than just a char array.  Declare `arr` as `char arr[11] = {0};//extra space for null termination

```
printf("%s\n", arr);//to print the string
```

Regarding this part of your stated objective:

> I shall also have to find the number of a certain element and print it on the screen.

The steps below are offered to modify the following work

```
int findTotal(){
    
}
```

- Change prototype to:

  `int FindTotal(char *arr);`
- count each occurrence of unique element in array ([How to reference](https://codeforwin.org/2015/07/c-program-to-find-frequency-of-each-element-in-array.html))
- Adapt above reference to use printf and formatting to match your stated output. ([How to reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65091366/645128))

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the number of elements You write in an array.
Array in C is just a space in the memory.
C does not know what elements are actual data.

But there are common ways to solve this problem in C:

- as mentioned above, create an array with one extra element and, fill the element after the last actual element with zero ('\0'). Zero means the end of the actual data. It is right if you do not wish to use '\0' among characters to be processed. It is similar to null-terminated strings in C.
- add the variable to store the number of elements in an array. It is similar to Pascal-strings.

  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>

  #define ARRAY_SIZE 10

  char array[ARRAY_SIZE + 1];

  int array_len(char * inp_arr) {
  int ret_val = 0;
  while (inp_arr[ret_val] != '\0')
  ++ret_val;
  return ret_val;
  }

  float array_with_level[ARRAY_SIZE];
  int array_with_level_level;

  int main() {

  ```
   array[0] = '\0';
   memcpy(array, "hello!\0", 7); // 7'th element is 0
   printf("array with 0 at the end\n");
   printf("%s, length is %d\n", array, array_len(array));

   array_with_level_level = 0;
   const int fill_level = 5;

   int iter;
   for (iter = 0; iter < fill_level; ++iter) {
       array_with_level[iter] = iter*iter/2.0;
   }
   array_with_level_level = iter;

   printf("array with length in the dedicated variable\n");
   for (int i1 = 0; i1 < array_with_level_level; ++i1)
       printf("%02d:%02.2f ", i1, array_with_level[i1]);
   printf(", length is %d", array_with_level_level);

   return 0;
  ```

  }

Comment: Could you please type me out the whole code. I can't really get what you are trying to convey

Comment: Except if the array has a well-know size... If you know that the size if 10, you can count the number of distinct elements.

Comment: _"There is no way to get the number of elements "_   Yes, there is.

Comment: @JiteshMoganaRaja It is in the answer now

Answer (score 0):

I use an array to count the number of the existence of each character,
I did this code but the display of number of each character is repeated in the loop

```
int main()
{
char arr[100];
printf("Give a text :");
gets(arr);
int k=strlen(arr);
for(int iterator=0; iterator<k; iterator++)
{
    printf("[%c]",arr[iterator]);
}
int T[k];
for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
{
    T[i]=arr[i];
}
int cpt1=0;
char d;
for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
{int cpt=0;
     for(int j=0;j<k;j++)
     {
          if(T[i]==T[j])
          {
               cpt++;
          }
     }
     if(cpt>cpt1)
     {
          cpt1=cpt;
          d=T[i];
     }
     printf("\nTotal alphabet %c : %d \n",T[i],cpt);
   }
   printf("\nAlphabet with highest hit is : %c\n",d,cpt1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`<conio.h>` is a non-standard header. I assume you're using Turbo C/C++ because it's part of your course. Turbo C/C++ is a terrible implementation (in 2020) and the only known reason to use it is because your lecturer made you!

However everything you actually use here is standard. I believe you can remove it.

`printf("%c",arr);` doesn't make sense. `arr` will be passed as a pointer (to the first character in the array) but `%c` expects a character value. I'm not sure what you want that line to do but it doesn't look useful - you've listed the array in the for-loop.
I suggest you remove it. If you do don't worry about a `\0`. You only need that if you want to treat `arr` as a string but in the code you're handling it quite validly as an array of 10 characters without calling any functions that expect a string. That's when it needs to contain a 0 terminator.

Also add `return 0;` to the end of `main()`. It means 'execution successful' and is required to be conformant.

With those 3 changes an input of `ABCDEFGHIJ` produces:

```
Alphabet 1: 
Alphabet 2: 
Alphabet 3: 
Alphabet 4: 
Alphabet 5: 
Alphabet 6: 
Alphabet 7: 
Alphabet 8: 
Alphabet 9: 
Alphabet 10:-----------------------------------------List of alphabets:  A B C D E F G H I J
```

It's not pretty but that's what you asked for and it at least shows you've successfully read in the letters. You may want to tidy it up...
Remove `printf("\nAlphabet %d:", count);` and insert  `printf("\nAlphabet %d: %c", count,arr[iterator]);` after `scanf(" %c", &arr[iterator]);`.
Put a newline before and after the line of minus signs (`printf("\n-----------------------------------------\n");` and it looks better to me.
But that's just cosmetics. It's up to you.

There's a number of ways to find the most frequent character. But at this level I recommend a simple nested loop.

Here's a function that finds the most common character (rather than the count of the most common character) and if there's a tie (two characters with the same count) it returns the one that appears first.

```
char findCommonest(const char* arr){
    char commonest='@'; //Arbitrary Bad value!
    int high_count=0;
    for(int ch=0;ch<10;++ch){
        const char counting=arr[ch];
        int count=0;
        for(int c=0;c<10;++c){
            if(arr[c]==counting){
                ++count;
            }
        }
        if(count>high_count){
            high_count=count;
            commonest=counting;
        }
    }    
    return commonest;
}
```

It's not very efficient and you might like to put some `printf`s in to see why!
But I think it's at your level of expertise to understand. Eventually.

Here's a version that unit-tests that function. Never write code without a unit test battery of some kind. It might look like chore but it'll help debug your code.

https://ideone.com/DVy7Cn

Footnote: I've made minimal changes to your code. There's comments with some good advice that you shouldn't hardcode the array size as 10 and certainly not litter the code with that value (e.g. `#define ALPHABET_LIST_SIZE (10)` at the top).
I have used `const` but that may be something you haven't yet met. If you don't understand it and don't want to learn it, remove it.

The terms of your course will forbid plagiarism. You may not cut and paste my code into yours. You are obliged to understand the ideas and implement it yourself. My code is very inefficient. You might want to do something about that!