# Align printf() columns on console display and prevent overrun to next line?

Tags: c

```
printf("| processid\t+ threadid\t| refilling\t| drinking\t| thinking\t| 
        waiting\t| terminated\t| p_type\t| required\t| consumed\t| 
        wake_count\t| turnaround_time\t\t+\n");

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    printf("|%d\t\t| %d\t\t| %d\t\t\t| %d\t\t\t| \
        %d\t\t\t| %d\t\t\t| %d\t\t\t\t|%s\t\t| \
        %d\t\t\t| %d\t\t| %d\t\t| %d\t\t|\n", 
            pcb[i].processid, pcb[i].threadid, 
            (pcb[i].t_state == 1)?1:0, 
            (pcb[i].t_state == 2)?1:0, 
            (pcb[i].t_state == 3)?1:0, 
            (pcb[i].t_state == 4)?1:0, 
            (pcb[i].t_state == 5)?1:0, 
            (pcb[i].p_type == Student)?"Student": "Bartender", 
            pcb[i].light_beer_required, 
            pcb[i].light_beer_consumed, 
            pcb[i].wake_count, 
            pcb[i].turnaround_time);
}
```

[See the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyo4w.png)

I want to align the table in such a way that the data falls under their respective columns but the table columns do not stay in one line.

How do I correct this issue?

Comment: An alternative way is to generate an html file with a table that has 100% width and view it in the browser.

Comment: The [C continuation character](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=C+line+continuation+characters) might be useful to you when coding a long statement, such as you have in your question.

Comment: You can use `column` utility in command line to post-process the unaligned output of your program.

Comment: @mbaitoff - It might be useful to say in what environment `column` utility is viable.

Answer (score 2):

Tabs do have their place, but are too rigid to use for aligning *variable length* data items into *constant width* columns.
`printf()` - `sprintf()` format padding, width specifiers, left and right justification techniques are all useful for what you want to do.  There is a reference link at bottom that describes details for these and other methods.

Things to consider in designing your table:

- What is the available total field width (width to be shared by all columns)
- What will be the maximum field width allowed for each column
- formatting should ensure data to be written to columns does not exceed width of its column (truncate strings, use fewer significant digits in numbers, etc.)
- Use flexible formatting techniques such as padding, justification, etc in the format specifiers to match expected data width requirements. (See examples below.)

The following code provides a few examples of using these techniques:

```
printf("|%-10d|, |%10d|\n", 1, 2);//left and right justtification within field
int pad1 = 5;
int pad2 = 10;
printf("|%.*d|, |%.*d|\n", pad1, 1, pad2, 2);//"*", variable padding  within field  
printf("|%-15s|\n", "string");// - left justifies
printf("|%15s|\n", "another string");// - right justifies
char *pad = "          "; //10 spaces
printf("|%s%*s|\n", pad, -9, "string");//combination of padding and justification
```

Given the following parameter assumptions:

```
typedef enum {
    Student,
    Bartender
}enum_e;   

typedef struct {
    int processid;
    int threadid;
    int t_state;
    enum_e p_type;
    int light_beer_required;
    int light_beer_consumed;
    int wake_count;
    int turnaround_time;
} pcb_s;
    
pcb_s pcb[3] = { {1234, 3, 1, Student, 1, 1, 2, 12},
                 {2345, 2, 2, Bartender, 1, 1, 2, 12},
                 {3456, 1, 3, Student, 1, 1, 2, 12} };
```

...Following is your code, modified to use just one of the techniques:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
 //   printf("|%d\t\t| %d\t\t| %d\t\t\t| %d\t\t\t| \
        %d\t\t\t| %d\t\t\t| %d\t\t\t\t|%s\t\t| \
        %d\t\t\t| %d\t\t| %d\t\t| %d\t\t|\n", 
   printf("|%10d|%3d|%3d|%3d|%3d|%3d|%3d|%15s|%3d|%3d|%3d|%d|\n", 
            pcb[i].processid, pcb[i].threadid, 
            (pcb[i].t_state == 1)?1:0, 
            (pcb[i].t_state == 2)?1:0, 
            (pcb[i].t_state == 3)?1:0, 
            (pcb[i].t_state == 4)?1:0, 
            (pcb[i].t_state == 5)?1:0, 
            (pcb[i].p_type == Student)?"Student": "Bartender", 
            pcb[i].light_beer_required, 
            pcb[i].light_beer_consumed, 
            pcb[i].wake_count, 
            pcb[i].turnaround_time);
    }
```

output of above:
[image]

[Here is a resource](https://www.cypress.com/file/54441/download) that goes into detail about these and many other formatting techniques.