# Can someone tell me why the functions are not returning a value? New to C

Tags: c, function

This code is just supposed to get the income, the expenses, then do some calculations in the third function. I am not sure where the problem is, when I run it, I keep getting the value 0.00. This is a personal project me and a friend are doing to help get some experience with C. Could it be something with the switch statement?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

struct expense 

{ 
char name[50]; 
float amount; 
}; 

struct income
{
    char name[50];
    float amount;
};

float getExpense(void); 
float getIncome(void); 
float budgetCalc(float sum_exp, float sum_inc);

int main() 

{ 
    float sum_exp, sum_inc;
    int option; 
    printf("\t\t**************************************************************************\n");
    printf("\t\t*     Thank you for choosing Ford$ as your personal budget tracker!      *\n");
    printf("\t\t*                                                                        *\n");
    printf("\t\t*                                                                        *\n");
    printf("\t\t* The goal of this program is to allow you track your finances! You may  *\n");
    printf("\t\t* enter your specified expenses, income streams. The amount for each of  *\n");
    printf("\t\t* the expenses and income. Then, the results will be displayed. You will *\n");
    printf("\t\t* be brought back to the selection-screen after you have entered your    *\n");
    printf("\t\t* data. From the selection-screen, if you are finished, you may quit the *\n");
    printf("\t\t* program if you are finished by selecting 0. The first feature will     *\n");
    printf("\t\t* give you the option to enter your income. The second feature is the    *\n");
    printf("\t\t* expenses feature. The third will do some calculations with the given   *\n");
    printf("\t\t* details but only after you have entered your data from the first and   *\n");
    printf("\t\t* the second feature!                                                    *\n");
    printf("\t\t*                                                                        *\n");
    printf("\t\t*                   Made by ****** ******* & ***** ****                  *\n");
    printf("\t\t*                                                                        *\n");
    printf("\t\t*                                                                        *\n");
    printf("\t\t*                                                                        *\n");    
    printf("\t\t*                   Please select a feature from below:                  *\n");
    printf("\t\t*                                                                        *\n");
    START:printf("\t\t*********************************Features**********************************\n\n\t\t\t\t    \t\t");
    printf("(1) Track Income \n\t\t\t\t\t\t");
    printf("(2) Track Expenses \n\t\t\t\t\t\t");
    printf("(3) Calculator \n\t\t\t\t\t\t");
    printf("(0) Exit \n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t");
    printf("Enter: ");
    scanf("%d", &option);

    switch(option){
        case 1:
            getIncome();
            goto START;
        case 2:
            getExpense();
            goto START;
        case 3:
            budgetCalc(sum_exp, sum_inc);
            goto START;
        case 0:
            printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\tThank you for choosing Ford$!");
            printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\tNOW EXITING PROGRAM.....");
            exit;
    }
    
    return 0; 

}
```

This gives us our expenses entered by the user. Uses the struct expense to store the values and an array, both this and income work fine.

```
float getExpense(){ 

struct expense arr_expense[1]; 

    int i; 
    int num_exp;  
    float sum_exp=0; 

    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tHow many expenses do you have? "); 
    scanf("%d", &num_exp); 

    for(i = 0; i < num_exp; i++ ) 
    { 
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\tEnter details of Expense %d\n\n", i+1); 
        printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tEnter name of the bill: "); 
        scanf("%s", arr_expense[i].name); 
        printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tEnter amount of payment: "); 
        scanf("%f", &arr_expense[i].amount); 
    } 

    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\tName:\t\tAmount:\t\n"); 

    for(i = 0; i < num_exp; i++ ) 
    { 
        printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t%s\t\t%.2f\n", 
        arr_expense[i].name, arr_expense[i].amount); 
    } 

    for(i = 0; i < num_exp; i++) 
    { 
        sum_exp = sum_exp + arr_expense[i].amount; 
    } 

    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\tTotal expenses are: $%.2f\n\n", sum_exp); 

    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tNOW RETURNIG TO SELECTION-SCREEN.....\n");

    return sum_exp;

}
```

This gives us our income entered by the user. Uses struct income to store the income with an array, then shows the results at the end.

```
float getIncome(){

    struct income arr_income[1];
    int i; 
    int num_inc;  
    float sum_inc=0; 

    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tHow many forms of income do you have? "); 
    scanf("%d", &num_inc); 

    for(i = 0; i < num_inc; i++ ) 
    { 
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\tEnter details of Income %d\n\n", i+1); 
        printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tEnter name of the Income stream: "); 
        scanf("%s", arr_income[i].name); 
        printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tEnter the amount paid to you: "); 
        scanf("%f", &arr_income[i].amount); 
    } 

    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\tName:\t\tAmount:\t\n"); 

    for(i = 0; i < num_inc; i++ ) 
    { 
        printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t%s\t\t%.2f\n", 
        arr_income[i].name, arr_income[i].amount); 
    } 

    for(i = 0; i < num_inc; i++) 
    { 
        sum_inc = sum_inc + arr_income[i].amount; 
    } 

    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\tTotal Income is: $%.2f\n\n", sum_inc); 

    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tNOW RETURNIG TO SELECTION-SCREEN.....\n");

    return sum_inc;
}
```

This function runs some calculations with the given data. For now, it is just supposed to show the value of income. But the only thing shown here is the value 0.00 instead of the actual value. I think it has something to do with the functions and passing but I can't see where it is going wrong.

```
float budgetCalc(float sum_inc, float sum_exp){
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tYou earn $%.2f! ", sum_inc);
}
```

Comment: For example the function budgetCalc does not have a return statement. And it does not even use the parameter sum_exp.

Comment: You call `getExpense()`, but you don't capture the return value.

Comment: Same with `getIncome()`.

Comment: `struct income arr_income[1];` is an array of size one.  What are you iterating over?

Comment: @Jr_23,  The silence is deafening.  If needed you can comment any questions or other in the comments here or under answers...

Comment: As for budgetCalc, I see what you mean. I only had the sum_inc in there to test if anything was going through. Thanks everyone who has helped with this, just trying to learn something new with covid restricting a lot of things. I will come back later on and let you all know how it goes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This array: `struct income arr_income[1];` is defined with 1 element, and later attempts to access more than 1 element, causing your program to invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Change this:(both here and similar in `getExpense()`)

```
struct income arr_income[1];
int i; 
int num_inc;  
float sum_inc=0; 

printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tHow many forms of income do you have? "); 
scanf("%d", &num_inc);
```

To this:  using a [Variable Length Array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-length-arrays-in-c-and-c/)

```
int i; 
int num_inc;  
float sum_inc=0; 

printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tHow many forms of income do you have? "); 
scanf("%d", &num_inc); 
struct income arr_income[num_inc] ={0};//correctly sized VLA (array) of struct.
```

*"Can someone tell me why the functions are not returning a value?"*
They are, but your code is not reading the returned value.
This segment is missing the lvalues:

```
switch(option){
    case 1:
        getIncome();// this function returns a value, but value is lost
        goto START;
    case 2:
        getExpense();//ditto
        goto START;
```

Change it to:

```
switch(option){
    case 1:
        sum_inc = getIncome();//return value is captured in sum_inc
        goto START;
    case 2:
        sum_exp = getExpense();//return value is captured in sum_exp 
        goto START;
```

Finally, regarding this section:

```
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\tEnter details of Expense %d\n\n", i+1); 
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tEnter name of the bill: "); 
    scanf("%s", arr_expense[i].name); 
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tEnter amount of payment: "); 
    scanf("%f", &arr_expense[i].amount);
```

There are some tips and suggestions for replacing the `\t` character with more [flexible formatting techniques here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65092323/645128).

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try your recommendations later in the day, I just woke up.

Answer (score 0):

In `getIncome`, you create an array of size 1:

```
struct income arr_income[1];
```

Then attempt to loop through `num_inc` array elements.  This writes past the end of the array, invoking undefined behavior.

You should define the array *after* you read the value of `num_inc`, then use that value for the size of the array.

```
scanf("%d", &num_inc);
struct income arr_income[num_inc];
```

The `getExpense` function has the same problem.

Also, you're not using the return value of these two functions.  You need to assign their return value to the associated variables in `main` for them to have a meaningful value.

```
    case 1:
        sum_inc = getIncome();
        goto START;
    case 2:
        sum_ext = getExpense();
        goto START;
```

As a side note, this isn't a good place to use `goto`.  Use a loop instead.

Comment: Thank you, I will try adjusting my code later on and let everyone know how it turns out.